# Convergence of an improper integral involving $\log(1+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is the following integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
divergent?

Comment: Also note that $\int x^\alpha \log(x) d x$ converges near $+\infty$ iff $\alpha < -1$ (by partial integration).